# assistance with postinstall script on Mac

Tags: macos, shell

New at this. I need to use a postinstall script to move a file and a folder to the user's Application Support folder on a Mac. For the file I only want to move it if the file doesn't already exist. I do not want to overwrite it if if does exist. Here is my script. It runs but nothing gets copied. I'm using the Packages app, btw, and this script is loaded into the postinstall script tab.

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! "/Library/Application Support/MyApp/MyApp user dict"; then 
mv "$1/Contents/Resources/MyApp user dict" "/Library/Application Support/MyApp/.";
fi

mv "$1/Contents/Resources/Spellcheck Dictionary" "/Library/Application Support/MyApp/.";
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

User-specific tasks generally do not belong in installer scripts -- remember that there may be multiple users on a machine, and that some of them may not be accessible when your installer is running. (For example, users may have encrypted home directories, or may not exist until after your installer is run.) If your application needs to copy files to the user's home directory, it should probably do this when it is first launched.

Nevertheless, I see several specific issues with this script:

1. Your script refers to `$1` in several places. Are you sure that your script has an argument passed to it on the command line?
2. The correct syntax to test if a file does not exist is:

   ```
   if [ ! -f "/path/to/file" ] ; then …
   ```

   Your script is missing the square brackets and `-f` condition. (For details, see `man test`.)
3. Assuming that `$1` is supposed to be the path to the current user's home directory, you have the arguments to `mv` backwards. The destination comes last, not first. (The syntax is essentially `mv from to`.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. So instead of using the installer, I should have my s/w check to see if the file and folder exist and move it there each time it's opened? I thought using the installer script could avoid that, but I suppose I shouldn't for the reasons you specified. Helpful to know the syntax, though, thanks.

Comment: Should probably be copying the file, not moving it. Otherwise, yes.